# Is possible to know the updated files when starting a new build in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When a new build is starting in Azure DevOps pipeline, is it possible to know which files are updated compared to the last build?

In other words, how to know the Head of the last build in the new build?

Comment: Agree with Shayki Abramczyk. This task could show the "Head" in the build log. But you need to set the variable `system.debug=true` in the pipeline, then you could get it in the debug log. If the answer could meet your requirements, you may consider accepting it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not a server admin,  I couldn't install this extension.  Is it possible to use a bash script to get the same information?

Comment: @Jim you can try to write a script that uses `git-diff` command https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Changed files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=touchify.vsts-changed-files) extension from the marketplace, it's a pipeline task to get changed files since the last succeeded build.

```
- task: ChangedFiles@1
  name: CheckChanges
  inputs:
    rules: src/**/*.ts
    variable: HasChanged
```